# How to retrieve a document id from a custom rule created in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

I have a Alfresco Comunity Manager 5.0

In Alfresco's configuration, I have created this rule: when an image is uploaded at any folder, it automatically generates a thumbnail from that image into a specific folder.

I am uploading documents to Alfresco using a Java's web service. The problem is how to retrieve the Alfresco's document id (this is... the 12344414341;0.1) from the thumbnail generated in that folder.

I am already retrieving the Alfresco's document id from the uploaded image (the original), but I don't know how to retrieve the one generated by the created rule. I guess it could be solved with a cmis query, but I am completely new to this.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit: rule details

1. Rule type: inbound
2. Conditions: Element has a mimetype "JPEG Image"
3. Actions: copy image to "thumbnails" and transform it with "-thumbnail 365x275"
4. Details: Apply this rule to subspaces, title "on create - thumbnail".

Comment: You wanted to get Id of uploaded document ?

Comment: The process is: 
- I upload a document,
- The rule in Alfresco's configuration folder where the document is uploaded generates a thumbnail (in this case for images) into another folder.
- I get the id from the document uploaded, but I don't know how to get the id from the document generated by the rule

Comment: From where/when are you trying to get thumbnail's ID?

Answer (score 2):

The challenge is that all you have is a reference to the uploaded document and rules do not return values. Based on the uploaded document, you'd like to get a reference to the thumbnail your rule generated.

The best way to do this would be to generate a pointer or reference to the generated thumbnail. A common way to do this is with associations, but you could also set a property on the uploaded document that has the node reference of the thumbnail as its value. Either way, given a reference to the uploaded document you can always get to the thumbnail by either following the association or grabbing the thumbnail's node reference from the property value.

Another alternative would be to store the thumbnail in a location that is easily retrievable given the reference to the original document. This is one reason why Alfresco stores thumbnails as renditions, which are persisted as children of the document they are thumbnails of. You too could store your thumbnail as a rendition. In fact, you could configure the thumbnail service to generate the thumbnail for you, and it will automatically be stored alongside other renditions.

If you use one of these suggestions you'll have to use either a custom rule action or the "execute script" action to point to your custom server-side JavaScript. In that script you will implement the logic depending on whichever alternative described above works best for you.

Last, be aware that what you included as an example "Alfresco document ID" looks to me like a CMIS object ID. That is different from an Alfresco node reference. Sometimes Alfresco will accept either one, but you should be conscious of which one you are using to avoid potential confusion.